# BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss and Loss/regularization_loss also zero using Tensorflow Objectdetection API

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, tensor, loss-function, object-detection-api

I have now been trying to train a object-detection model for some time, namely the "faster_rcnn_resnet152_v1_640x640_coco17_tpu-8" model. However, during this whole training process, neither the BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss or the Loss/regularization_loss has been higher than zero.

Has anyone else had similar issues, or do anyone know a solution?
(I think this is the reason why my model performs very very poorly atleast)

```
INFO:tensorflow:{'Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss': 0.011540242,
 'Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss': 0.0,
 'Loss/RPNLoss/localization_loss': 0.05603733,
 'Loss/RPNLoss/objectness_loss': 0.021345321,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.0,
 'Loss/total_loss': 0.08892289,
 'learning_rate': 0.090500005}
I1105 01:40:26.982768 16300 model_lib_v2.py:705] {'Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss': 0.011540242,
 'Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss': 0.0,
 'Loss/RPNLoss/localization_loss': 0.05603733,
 'Loss/RPNLoss/objectness_loss': 0.021345321,
 'Loss/regularization_loss': 0.0,
 'Loss/total_loss': 0.08892289,
 'learning_rate': 0.090500005}
```

Answer (score 0):

'localization_loss' always staying at 0.0 can be due to an error in your tfrecords-file, or, most likely an error in your label_map. Check if your label_map matches with the classes in your tfrecords-file and is correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

When your localization and regularization loss is zero, it means there is some problem with generating tfrecords files. When creating annotations for image files your labels should be consistent with you label map file.

Extract from example tf record

```
feature {
    key: "image/object/class/text"
    value {
      bytes_list {
        value: "paragraph"
        value: "paragraph"
        value: "table"
        value: "paragraph"
      }
    }
  }
```

Now when you create labelmap.pbtxt it should exactly match with above values

Extract from sample labelmap file

```
item {
 name: "paragraph"
 id: 1
     }
item {
 name: "table"
 id: 2
     }
```

After making this change you localization_loss should not be zero anymore.